# How to create a zip installation file for a WordPress dynamic block?

Tags: wordpress, installation, zip, gutenberg-blocks

I've created a dynamic gutenberg block and I'm trying to create a installation zip file.

As it's a dynamic block, I need to include some PHP files which I've put in the files section of the package.json file:

```js
    "files": [
        "/build",
        "plugin.js",
        "plugin.php",
        "functions-library.php"
    ],
```

If I run the npm command for the plugin-zip package, I get a zip file which includes the build directory but not the files that are also specified above.

Just wondering how I can include the specified files?

I've also tried creating the zip file manually, so it contains the above files and the build directory. The block installs OK and I've activated it. When I edit a page and try to add the block, I can't as it isn't listed as an available block. Does anyone else know what needs to be included in the zip file?

I've tried googling this but found practically nothing.

Comment: In the past, I found that the name for the plugin defined in the package.json file has to match the name of the main php file.

i.e. in the package.json if name="myproject"
The main php file should be called myproject.php.

I've done this but still don't get the php files in the zip file.